# C++ copy constructor incorrectly takes argument

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have the following code that behaves weirdly. The flow I understood so far is, `display(line);` will call the copy constructor `Line::Line(const Line &obj)`, and the reference of `line` will be passed in. However `cout<<"[origin] *ptr="<<*obj.ptr<<endl;` will print `[origin] *ptr=32767` instead of `[origin] *ptr=10`.

The more weird thing is, if I uncomment `// int x=3;`, it will print correctly, but I really have no idea why.

You may find the executable code at: https://www.onlinegdb.com/pjbPO0X1f

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
class Line
{
   public:
      int getLength( void );
      Line( int len );
      Line( const Line &obj);

   private:
      int *ptr;
};
 
// constructor
Line::Line(int len)
{
    ptr=&len;
    cout<<"*ptr="<<(*ptr)<<endl;
}

// copy constructor
Line::Line(const Line &obj)
{
    // int x=3;
    cout<<"[origin] *ptr="<<*obj.ptr<<endl;
    ptr = new int;
    *ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy
}

int Line::getLength( void )
{
    return *ptr;
}
 
void display(Line obj)
{
   cout << "line=" << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

int main( )
{
   Line line(10);
   display(line);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The simple comment is -- don't write C++ code this way.  Why introduce pointers when there is no need to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You program invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (UB). When your constructor finishes:

```
Line::Line(int len)
{
    ptr=&len;
    cout<<"*ptr="<<(*ptr)<<endl;
} // ptr is dangling
```

the pointer `ptr` is pointing to a local variable `len`, which no longer exists. `ptr` is now dangling, and any attempt at dereferencing it invokes UB.

Your program may do anything at all. You can also see some strange results like adding `int x = 3` resulting in your program "behaving correctly". Don't worry about why this happens, it's just a result of UB.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common error (although this is a strange version of it).

This code is wrong

```
// constructor
Line::Line(int len)
{
    ptr=&len;
    cout<<"*ptr="<<(*ptr)<<endl;
}
```

`ptr` is made to point to `len` but `len` is a local variable. It is destroyed when the constructor is exited. This means you have a pointer to an object which no longer exists. Sometimes this is called a *dangling pointer*.

Then later in the code you use this pointer

```
cout<<"[origin] *ptr="<<*obj.ptr<<endl;
```

Since the pointer is now invalid, the effects are unpredictable.

One of the many things that make pointers difficult is that the lifetime of a pointer and the lifetime of what it is pointing at are not connected in any way at all. It's up to you to make sure that your pointers are always pointing at objects that are still 'alive'.